# GWT Security regarding XSS

Tags: security, gwt, xss

I'm building a GWT Application. But i dont want user to enter any html or javascript. No entry should be interpreted as html or javascript. Could you suggest any java libary that fit my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your responsibility to sanitize user input, but GWT does do a great deal of XSS protection on it's own. You could do a basic sanitization using GWT's built in `SimpleHtmlSanitizer.sanitizeHtml(input);`

Comment: I've found the built in Sanitizer doesn't have a lot of tags in it's whitelist. You may very well need more than it can provide.

Comment: GWT works to sanitize most outputs. The key here is that most injection attacks want to put malicious JS/HTML into the page to attack users. GWT is very good at preventing that via the obj.setInnerText() instead of obj.setInnerHTML() & the SafeHTML and SafeCSS interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

The HtmlSanitizer interface documentation clearly says "SafeHtml should not be used to sanitize input before sending it to the server." So if you "dont want user to enter any html or javascript", then this is not the solution.